# Change g:link behavior in grails

Tags: url, grails, taglib

I was looking for a way to change the default g:link behavior of Grails, but I can't figure out what I have to do, extend some class, configure a bean spring...
Does someone have some suggest?

Comment: In what way do you want to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your own TagLib and define the link clojure, it will override the default grails link tag.

```
class MyTagLib {
  def link = { attrs, body ->
    out << 'changing the default grails link'
  }
}
```

Comment: ok and if I want to use the old link closure in this new one? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, checkout the `ApplicationTagLib` class. This have the link clojure. If i'm not mistaken `g.link` will do the trick, or look for how to get the ApplicationTagLib instance.